# Parse only the IP address from resolvectl

Tags: linux, bash, cut

I want to cut only the IP address. I tried `cut -d':' -f1` but that takes other words that I don't want.

```
resolvectl query remote.geo.com
```

but I have :

```
remote.geo.com: X.X.X.X           -- link: enp0s31f6
```

I want only

```
X.X.X.X
```

I can take the first line but there are other words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most modern commands, [`resolvectl`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/resolvectl.1.html) has a flag to turn off decorations, which makes it somewhat easier to parse its output.

```sh
resolvectl query --legend=false remote.geo.com | awk '{print $2}'
```

If you are not hellbent on using `resolvectl`, you can get machine-readable output from `dig` or (some versions of) `host`:

```sh
dig +short remote.geo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`:

```
remote.geo.com: X.X.X.X -- link: enp0s31f6|awk '{print $2}'
```

as `cut` will fail if the delimiter is `' '` and there are more than one `spaces` in there..

Answer (score 1):

You could `cut` by the space and take the second field:

```
resolvectl query remote.geo.com | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resolvectl query remote.geo.com|grep -oE '[[:space:]][[0-9.]+[[:space:]]'|tr -d '[:space:]'
```

The regexp is bounded on both sides by a space, to avoid strings of digits to be picked up in other fields of the output (such as in the link information), and the `tr` removes them afterwards.